# Jquery prevent device keyboard from re-sizing browser content

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, keyboard

I have site that scales everything to fit the users mobile device screen. But when the default keyboard is brought up the whole site is rescaled. It is possible to have the keyboard overlay the website so to not distort the site or zoom and focus on the particular input field the user has touched.

[image: what it should like]
This what I thought would happen or a very similar effect.

But this is what is happening
[image]

The content on right remains unchanged. This has a fixed width but positioned to fit:

```
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
```

The pages are sized and scaled on the page load. These are set heights and widths. E.g if the height is 600px then the width would be 800px.

```
    var windowWidth = parseInt(window.innerWidth);
    var windowHeight = parseInt(window.innerHeight);    
    //set content height 90% of windowHeight
    var c_height = windowHeight / 100 * 95;
    var c_width = c_height * 1.48;
    $('#content').css('height',c_height+'px');
    $('#content').css('width',c_width+'px');
```

I came across something similar to this, but have had no success:

```
function updateViews() {
    $('#page').hide();
    if (is_keyboard) {
        $("#page").hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#page').show();
    }
}
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    is_keyboard = (window.innerHeight < initial_screen_size);
    is_landscape = (screen.height < screen.width);

    updateViews();
}, false);
/* iOS */
$("input").bind("focus blur",function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(10);
    is_keyboard = $(window).scrollTop() > 0;
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
    updateViews();
});
```

This something I thought would have been defaulted by the device.

UPDATE:
if it helps all the page content is wrapped in a div;

```
<div id="body" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
```

Also the keyboard wont open any other input only the bar at the top.

Answer (score 2):

Try This out, I am developing for a mobile, and my page is fixed so this might work.

```
<div id="body" style="width:100%; height:100%; position: fixed">
```

Comment: Sort of worked I also had to take out the function to rescale my pages when the browser re sizes. Kind of explains why only the pages were resizing

Comment: Yes, you can also capture the change in the screen and prevent it from resizing.